# How to resolve cx_Oracle connect not working: ORA-03113

Tags: python, oracle, database-connection, cx-oracle

I'm trying to connect to a remote oracle db with cx_Oracle. This has worked in the past, and I can connect using Oracle SQL developer, but using this keeps returning an error. This leads me to think it's a cx_Oracle issue, but any insight.

```
import cx_Oracle as orc 
user='usr'
pwd='pwd'
host='db.host.url'
service_name='servname'

db = orc.connect(user, pwd, '{}:1521/{}'.format(host,service_name)) #error is here
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path_to_py", line 15, in <module>
    db = orc.connect(user, pwd, '{}:1521/{}'.format(host,service_name))
cx_Oracle.OperationalError: ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

> Oracle SQL Developer version:
> 17.3.0
>
> Oracle Client version: 11.2.0
>
> Oracle DB hosted on azure
>
> Local platform: windows 10
>
> python version: 3.7
>
> cx_Oracle version: 7.0.0

Comment: Can you connect to the same database using SQL*Plus? If you can, it would help if you included the version number, platform, Oracle version, etc. in your question!

Comment: @AnthonyTuininga Sorry i'm not familiar with SQL*Plus, but i can connect with Oracle SQL Developer version 17.3.0. Will update question with this and oracle client info